# Want to call js method without onclick or onsubmit button of ajax in wicket

Tags: javascript, java, wicket

I want to call a js method in wicket without using event. For eg, please see below:

```
   public method(Page params) {      
      Form<?> form = new Form("dataform");       
      form.add(new AjaxFallbackButton("nextPages", form) {          
        @Override
        public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target,Form<?> form) {   
        //do something              
        }
    });
      add(form);
}
```

What I want to achieve is as follow:

```
  public method(Page params) {      
  Form<?> form = new Form("dataform");       
  form.add(new AjaxFallbackButton("nextPages", form) {          

    //do something              
        });
  add(form);
}
```

I dont want to use setInterval method as I am not sure how much time the user will take to fill the form.
Is there any other way through which I can call the js method?

Comment: You dont want to set time and also dont want to submit by user, then what exactly you want? Question is not clear here.

Comment: I want to call a js method but without the onSubmit method of Ajax like target.append or response.render etc

Answer (score 3):

I did not understand what you want to do exactly, but maybe you can use renderHead method on form creation:

```
public method(Page params) {
    Form<?> form = new Form("dataform"){
        @Override
        public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
            String js ="your js";
            response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript(js));
            super.renderHead(response);
        }
    };

    add(form);
}
```